# How to use Search bar with Navigaitonbar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have successfully get UISearchController to work in a new project, but when I am trying to do the same thing in my own project, it behaves differently.

This is what I have done to get it to work.

Storyboard:

[image: This is my storyboard]

This is my code for my view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {

    var searchController : UISearchController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let modalVC =  mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchTableViewController_SBID")
        self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:  modalVC)

        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.searchController.delegate = self
        self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

        self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true

        self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar

        self.definesPresentationContext = true
    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

The result I am getting is, when I click on the search bar, the background will be dimmed, and when I started typing, the tableview controller will be visible, will the search bar is still visible in the navigation bar in the tableview controller.

However, when I try to implement the same thing in my project, when I started typing on the search bar, the table view controller will fill the whole screen, and the navigation bar is not visible.

This is the storyboard for my project:

[image: Storyboard for my project]

Notice both projects are similar, except for one of them is `Navigation Controller -> Tab Bar View Controller`, which doesn't show the navigation bar when I type on the searchbar.

How do I get the navigation bar to show in a project `Navigation Controller -> Tab Bar View Controller`?

This is what it looks like for 2 projects:

[image: No navigation bar]

[image: Working project, visible bar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Storyboard Setup**

[image]
**Coding of both view controller**

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController,UISearchBarDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl1: UILabel!
    var searchBar:UISearchBar? = nil
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Code to identify the searchbar
        for view in (self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.titleView?.subviews)!
        {
            if view.isKind(of: UISearchBar.self)
            {
                searchBar = (view as! UISearchBar);
            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        //Assign Delegate and blank the search bar text 
        searchBar?.text = ""
        searchBar?.delegate = self

    }
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        lbl1.text = "Tab 1 : \(searchText)"

    }

}
class ViewController2: UIViewController,UISearchBarDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl1: UILabel!
    var searchBar:UISearchBar? = nil
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Code to identify the searchbar
        for view in (self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.titleView?.subviews)!
        {
            if view.isKind(of: UISearchBar.self)
            {
                searchBar = (view as! UISearchBar);
            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        searchBar?.text = ""
        searchBar?.delegate = self
    }
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        lbl1.text = "Tab 2 : \(searchText)"

    }

}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: I already have this line : self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:  modalVC), which is working in a clean project, just not working in a project with TabBar Controller

Comment: okey for tabbar controller you have embed each tab with navigation controller like i updated image

Comment: you did just reverse, just embed each view controller from tabbar to navigation view controller

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. I actually have problem with displaying navigation bar, with a search bar inside, while using tabbar, not as like you edited my title (how to use navigation bar with tabbar). I have no problem using navigation bar with tabbar throughout my whole projects.

Comment: If like you said each view controller of my tabbar I have to embed in nav controller, does that mean that if I have 5 tabs, I need to have 5 search bar for every tab?

Comment: yes you have to embed in nav controller to each tab, i think there is alternate way for search bar.

Comment: Ok thanks. If you know about any alternatives to the search bar, instead of creating 5 for my 5 tabs, please let me know. Ill accept your answer, thanks

Comment: @user3051673 as i told there is alternate way to do it , hope it works

Comment: Seems like a pretty gross hack to clear the text on view did appear. You will be clearing it on all kinds of situations you probably don't want it cleared. Even just navigating forward and back on a child view controller. Maybe your approach should be using `navigationItem.searchController = searchController` instead